# "includeAntRuntime" was not set for android ant script?

Tags: android, ant, sdk

"includeAntRuntime" was not set to false in the android ant script, and it gives me the annoying warning every time I build my app.

```
[javac] /Users/dwang/Library/android/android-sdk-mac_x86/tools/ant/main_rules.xml:361: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
```

Look at the line 354 of file android-sdk-*/tools/ant/main_rules.xml

```
            <javac encoding="${java.encoding}"
                    source="${java.source}" target="${java.target}"
                    debug="true" extdirs=""
                    destdir="${out.classes.absolute.dir}"
                    bootclasspathref="android.target.classpath"
                    verbose="${verbose}"
                    classpath="${extensible.classpath}"
                    classpathref="jar.libs.ref">
                <src path="${source.absolute.dir}" />
                <src path="${gen.absolute.dir}" />
                <src refid="project.libraries.src" />
                <classpath>
                    <fileset dir="${extensible.libs.classpath}" includes="*.jar" />
                </classpath>
            </javac>
```

And it seems I can not easily fix it without modifying that file directly? Android team, please fix it maybe?

Comment: http://www.enterra-inc.com/techzone/using_ant_android_applications_building/ may be helpful

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A workaround for the Android SDK is to set the [`build.sysclasspath`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/sysclasspath.html) property to `"last"` and that will suppress the false warning.

Do this by assigning the property value in the project's `build.properties` file.

```
# You can use this to override default values such as
#  'source.dir' for the location of your java source folder and
#  'out.dir' for the location of your output folder.
out.dir=build
gen.dir=build/gen

# Suppress the javac task warnings about "includeAntRuntime"
build.sysclasspath=last
```

Comment: Is build.properties also called ant.properties?

Comment: I haven't found build.properties and after i creating this file, this warning is still printed. But adding it to project.properties will solve this problem. 
Can i configure my SDK to make this code automatically add to project.properties when i create android project ?

Answer (score 1):

That's caused by a misfeature introduced in Ant 1.8. Just add an attribute of that name to the `javac` task, set it to false, and forget it ever happened.

ie. set the attribue `includeAntRuntime` in your `javac` Ant task. The Ant User Manual gives the following attribute description: "attribute `includeAntRuntime` defaults to yes, unless build.sysclasspath is set. It is usually best to set this to false so the script's behavior is not sensitive to the environment in which it is run".

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Actually that is easy fix, but not for the Android SDK. The target is defined in android sdk script.